# Android RecyclerView canScrollVertically issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I am checking if the scroll is at the bottom of recyclerview.
So many articles recommended me the RecyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) method.
But in my case, that method always returns false.

```
binding.studentsList.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
                Log.d("SCROLL", "canscrollDown ${recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)} State = $newState")
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING){
                    //do something
                }
            }
        })
```

Is there alternative way to check if the scroll is reached to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative way to check the bottom of a RecyclerView is by using the `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` and `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` of `LayoutManager`.

```
class LoadMoreScrollListener()
    : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){

    var onLoadMore: (() -> Unit)? = null
    var dataSize : Int = 0

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        if (dy == 0) return
        var layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager?

        if (layoutManager != null && layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == dataSize - 1) {
            onLoadMore?.invoke()
        }
    }
}



private val loadMoreScrollListener : LoadMoreScrollListener = LoadMoreScrollListener()
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(loadMoreScrollListener)
loadMoreScrollListener.onLoadMore = {
    // get more data 
    loadMoreScrollListener.dataSize = [newSize]
}
```

Hope it helps!